# Compare two managed properties in search criteria

Tags: enterprise-search, sharepoint-search

Is there a way to compare the value of a managed property with value from term set? I have a set of values which I want to compare with a managed property in my search criteria.

Comment: Please provide an example of what you mean.

Comment: Currently I have configure the search results webpart to filter results as 

{searchterms} (Country=India OR Country=Spain OR Country=USA)

where Country is my managed property. If the user requests to add one more country, i have change the criteria to include the new country. I wish if the list of countries could come from a dictionary, list, termset, etc.

Comment: You can do that with a Query Rule.

Comment: Any sample or article would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From memory, so the navigation might be a little off.

In your site or site collection choose site settings. Choose Query Rules and then create a new query rule using the option for matching a value in a Term Set. Pick your term set.

Configure the rest of the query rule as you like.

There is a good video on the topic here: https://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2017/08/07/search-based-site-directory-part-5/